# Laravel validation rules for JSON

Tags: json, laravel, validation

I'm trying to use a custom FormRequest with validation rules for JSON formatted data. If I use same code in controller instead of the FormRequest class then it works fine, see below:

array data (from ajax request):

```
[
  {
    "name": "id",
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "title",
    "value": "My fun project"
  }  
]
```

Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
    //convert it to readable json
    $jsonReq = $request->json()->all();
    $jsonData = array();
    foreach ($jsonReq as $json) {
        $jsonData[$json["name"]] = $json["value"];
    }

    $rules = [
        'id' => 'required|numeric:1',
        'title' => 'required|max:255',
    ];

    $validation = Validator::make($jsonData, $rules);

    if ($validation->fails()) {
      return $validation->errors();
    }
}
```

Above works fine when used in the controller. However, I want to separate my validation in a separate class, extending the FormRequest. This generates some errors, most likely due to the array format.

```
class UpdateProjectValidationRequest extends FormRequest {

      public function rules() {

        $jsonReq = $this->json()->all();
        $jsonData = array();
        foreach ($jsonReq as $json) {
            $jsonData[$json["name"]] = $json["value"];
        }

        return [
            'id' => 'required|max:1', //does not work
            $jsonData['title'] => 'required|max:255', //does not work
        ];
}
```

Controller:

```
  public function update(UpdateProjectValidationRequest $request, $id) {

    // validate against rules
    $request->rules();
```

The error message:

```
{
  "message": "The given data was invalid.",
  "errors": {
    "My fun project": [
      "My fun project field is required."
    ],
    "id": [
      "The id field is required."
    ],
```

Clearly this has to do with the format. Any ideas how to solve this? Note that after the foreach loop the data is formatted to below:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "title": "My Fun project",
}
```

Comment: maybe you need to parse the json into php, try to see first if it's parsed, by logging the values of the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i could not solve it using the laravel FormRequest, instead I modified the ajax call itself by serializing it to json instead of an array.

```
    $.fn.serializeObject = function()
    {
        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function() {
            if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                if (!o[this.name].push) {
                    o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                }
                o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
            } else {
                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }
        });
        return o;
    };
//old: var formdata = JSON.stringify(jQuery('#myForm').serializeArray());
var formdata = JSON.stringify(jQuery('#myForm').serializeObject());
```